# Impresión de una imagen png desde cmd

Tags: cmd

Alguien podria ayudarme para realizar una impresión de una imagen desde cmd, ademas la impresora es una hp puerto usb

Answer (score 2):

En esta [pregunta de StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11321919/3695983) puedes encontrar diferentes soluciones para lo que buscas. Personalmente me gusta [ésta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19903826/3695983) porque me parece una solución imaginativa y rápida:

```
mspaint /pt <FICHERO> <IMPRESORA>
```

Lo que hace es que imprime el fichero indicado desde MSPaint en la impresora especificada. Si no pones ninguna impresora, se manda a la impresora por defecto. Lo he probado en Windows 10 y funciona genial.

Así por ejemplo, si quieres imprimir el fichero imagen.png, irías al directorio en el que se encuentra y escribirías esto en la línea de comandos:

```
mspaint /pt imagen.png
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me funciono pero la imagen me imprime muy grande, sabrias como hacer para hacer mas pequeña la imagen?

Comment: @FranciscoOsorio deberias deberias aceptar la respuesta y crear un nuevo hilo solicitando ayuda para configurar las propiedades de la impresora desde cmd

Comment: @FranciscoOsorio Parece que a través de MSPaint no se puede seleccionar el tamaño de la imagen. Tendrías que probar con alguna otra solución para seleccionar el tamaño (podría hacerse con otras herramientas pero no serían nativas)

Comment: Ah bueno, gracias por el aporte